# How properties file in java works?

Tags: java, properties-file

I have used the properties file many times in java for storing the static values and removing the hard-coded code from the program. But I have used it for only few say hundreds of values. However I am curious about how actually the properties file works ?

How do they manipulate and store the values given in the file?

How efficient are they i.e. if we are using thousands of values in a properties file will it be equally efficient as the properties file with small values ? *if there is linear increase in processing required or there is high overhead of processing ?*

Comment: Did you have any issues?

Comment: @Puce as i stated in the question i am "curious". Actually i am working on some project and using properties file actually the device on which i am using this program has limited computational and memory resources that's why i wanted to know. However i have an alternative solution also, but still i want to know about it ,can you please refer some link where it is explained in details. thanks.

Comment: You could look at the source code to see the implementation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The Properties class extends Hashtable, so it is as efficient as Hashtable with String keys, which is pretty efficient.

Comment: @Prashant Yes, I knew it's the one or the other. Should have double checked before. Fixed my answer.

Answer (score 1):

One problem with manipulating a properties file using `java.util.Properties` is that will strip out any comments.

Considering using `org.apache.felix.utils.properties.Properties` instead (which is built on top of `java.util.AbstractMap<K,V>` from

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.apache.felix</groupId>
        <artifactId>org.apache.felix.utils</artifactId>
        <version>1.6.0</version>
    </depenency>
```

Which will retain, comments, order, white space etc.

The Performance cost of insertion is **O(log(n))** with the number of entries.

Answer (score 0):

you can see in code

```
public class Properties extends Hashtable<Object,Object>
 {
       // ... code
    }
```

it is extending `HashTable` class so its efficient and also you can check javadoc for `setProperty` , `store` and `load` method in `Properties` class.

Comment: okay, but still there is an overhead of reading it from file using streams and putting it into hastable. am i right ?

Comment: You are right!! in that case we can use our own method.

Comment: what do you mean by "own method" ? please explain ?

Comment: The IO performance cost will eclipse the cost of inserting into the Map by several orders of magnitude.  You really don't need to worry about it.

Comment: @Bruce_Wayne here i mean something like `ResourceBundle` but i am agree with @Donald

Answer (score 0):

Here's the [source code](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java); it's very straightforward. The file is [read](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java#l344) in one O(n) pass into a `Hashtable`, which has O(1) insertions and retrievals.[Writing](http://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/687fd7c7986d/src/share/classes/java/util/Properties.java#l823) the properties back to the file is similarly O(n). Thousands of keys, even tens of thousands of keys, will be no problem.

It sounds like you're envisioning the `Properties` class re-reads the file every time it's modified, or every time a property is accessed. This is not how `Properties` works, and it would be very wasteful to do so. `Properties` is essentially a glorified `Map` implementation with extra methods to read and write its contents to a file.